# Comparing a nullable datetime to a datetime using Linq to EF

Tags: c#, javascript, datetime, linq-to-entities, nullable

I have a database table field that is a nullable datetime. For some reason I can get the query below to work.

```
var requests = _db.Requests
               .Where(r => r.processedDate.Value == processDate);
```

I am 100% sure that I have four matching dates, but I keep getting nothing back. I have tried all kinds of variations on this query, but without success.

**Update**

The reason the compare doesn't work is that I am passing the processDate through a javascript function, like this

```
function Reprocess(processDate, spanid) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to re-process this batch?')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "?ajaxFunction=Reprocess",
            data: processDate,
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                $(spanid).html(data);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I do, I am forced to convert the DateTime to a string in order to pass it to my function.  When I convert it to a string it rounds of to seconds, and hence loses the miliseconds. Which is why the Linq query doesn't find any matches (because of 14 milliseconds).

How can I pass the full datetime value through javascript? Or will I have to compare on date, hour, minute, and second instead?

Comment: Post the matching dates, maybe.

Comment: The query looks correct. Please post the issue you are facing.

Comment: are the dates exactly the same (date, time, timezone, etc?)

Comment: Try changing your query as follows and see if it works:  .Where(r => r.processedDate.HasValue && r.processDate.Value==processDate)

Comment: Thanks guys, you got me on the right track. I finally compared the Ticks on the datetime object and noticed that there was a 14 millisecond difference. The reason for this is that at one point the date was converted to a string through javascript. The problem remains, but the question is now different. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're converting it to a string server-side, before it gets to your JavaScript, then try this:

C#

```
// Make sure processDateStr gets to your JavaScript function
string processDateStr = processDate.ToString("o");
```

And then when you get the string value back on the server again, use this to restore the same value:

```
DateTime processDate = DateTime.Parse(processDateStr, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

The value will be restored exactly as it was originally.

**EDIT**

The "o" format specifier is the round-trip specifier.  You can read more about it [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Roundtrip).

Comment: That worked- thanks! Much nicer than comparing everything from year to seconds.